# I have a column (array of strings), in a PySpark dataframe. How do I break the array and make separate rows for every string item in the array?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a PySpark dataframe:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([
    ("u1", ['u1_row1', 'u1_row2', 'u1_row3']),
    ("u2", ['u2_row1', 'u2_row2']),
    ("u3", ['u3_row1']),
    ],
    ['user_id', 'col_1'])

print(df.printSchema())
df.show()
```

It looks like:

```
+-------+--------------------+
|user_id|               col_1|
+-------+--------------------+
|     u1|[u1_row1, u1_row2...|
|     u2|  [u2_row1, u2_row2]|
|     u3|           [u3_row1]|
+-------+--------------------+
```

Now I want the arrays to be broken down in such a way that I get a new row for every string item in the array.
It should look like

```
+-------+---------------------------+
|user_id|               col_1_values|
+-------+---------------------------+
|     u1|                    u1_row1|
|     u1|                    u1_row2|
|     u1|                    u1_row3|
|     u2|                    u2_row1|
|     u2|                    u2_row2|
|     u3|                    u3_row1|
+-------+---------------------------+
```

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, using `explode_outer` can preserve rows with empty arrays. For example:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = spark.createDataFrame([
    ("u1", ['u1_row1', 'u1_row2', 'u1_row3']),
    ("u2", ['u2_row1', 'u2_row2']),
    ("u3", []),
    ],
    ['user_id', 'col_1'])
df.show()
+-------+---------------------------+
|user_id|col_1                      |
+-------+---------------------------+
|u1     |[u1_row1, u1_row2, u1_row3]|
|u2     |[u2_row1, u2_row2]         |
|u3     |[]                         |
+-------+---------------------------+

explode = df.withColumn('col_1_items', F.explode('col_1'))
explode.show()
+-------+--------------------+-----------+
|user_id|               col_1|col_1_items|
+-------+--------------------+-----------+
|     u1|[u1_row1, u1_row2...|    u1_row1|
|     u1|[u1_row1, u1_row2...|    u1_row2|
|     u1|[u1_row1, u1_row2...|    u1_row3|
|     u2|  [u2_row1, u2_row2]|    u2_row1|
|     u2|  [u2_row1, u2_row2]|    u2_row2|
+-------+--------------------+-----------+

explode_outer = df.withColumn('col_1_items', F.explode_outer('col_1'))
explode_outer.show()
+-------+--------------------+-----------+
|user_id|               col_1|col_1_items|
+-------+--------------------+-----------+
|     u1|[u1_row1, u1_row2...|    u1_row1|
|     u1|[u1_row1, u1_row2...|    u1_row2|
|     u1|[u1_row1, u1_row2...|    u1_row3|
|     u2|  [u2_row1, u2_row2]|    u2_row1|
|     u2|  [u2_row1, u2_row2]|    u2_row2|
|     u3|                  []|       null|
+-------+--------------------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df = df.withColumn('col_1_items', F.explode('col_1'))
```

It worked for me.